# Use of while loops

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program that asks the user how many years they want to insert and then let them insert a temperature for every month of that year so it looks like this:

---

How many years in total? e.g. 3

Which is the first year? e.g 2015

Month 1: 25

Month 2: 21

and so on...

---

for as many years as the user wants to see. This is what I have so far:

```
years = int(input("How many years?: "))

i= 0

while i <= years:
    for i in range(0,13):
            input("Type in first year")
            input("Month 1:  ")
            input("Month 2:  ")
            input("Month 3:  ")
            input("Month 4:  ")
            input("Month 5:  ")
            input("Month 6:  ")
            input("Month 7:  ")
            input("Month 8:  ")
            input("Month 9:  ")
            input("Month 10: ")
            input("Month 11: ")
            input("Month 12: ")
```

and this sort of works but is there a neater way to make the month number be +1 automatically and ask for input 12 times? And secondly, when I have done the whole first year it still asks me "Which is the first year" after I have typed in the temperatures for the 12 months but I want it to ask for the second, third etc. Like: "Which is the second year?")

I have tried to do it like this instead:

---

```
years = int(input("How many years?: "))

i= 0

monthnumber = 1 

while i <= years:

    for i in range(0,13):
            input("Which is the first year?: ")
            input("Month",monthnumber,": ")
            monthnumber += 1
```

---

Here I get the error message that input expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: One problem is You are using `i` for both loops. and assuming you got different variables, if it is your entire code for the `loops`, it is an `infinite` loop

Comment: Any suggestion for what I can do? Can I for instance write:   if monthnumber == 12 break?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
years_num = int(input("How many years?: "))

for year_num in range(1, years_num + 1):
    input("year " + str(year_num) + "?: ")
    for month_num in range(1, 13):
        input("month " + str(month_num) +":")
```

Then you can store the input information in a list or a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Separating by commas causes python to interpret it as multiple arguments.

What you want is to concatenate the strings to a single string, something that can be achieved by using the + operator.

`input("Month " + str(monthnumber) + ": ")`

Answer (score 0):

Few problems in your code. One is like I said in the comments, `index` variables are same for both the loops. Alsom in your inner loop, you are `iterating` asking for each month temperature inside each loop. Also, you are not holding temperatures anywhere. Here is a solution I recommend,

```
years = int(raw_input("Enter number of years: "))
#dictionary to hold year and temperature for each month for that year
temp = {}

for i in range(0, years):
    curr_year = raw_input("Enter current year: ")
    temp[curr_year] = []
    for i in range(0, 12):
        temp[curr_year].append((int(raw_input("Enter temperature: "))))
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/piuSYm) is the working version of the code above